# Substitute zero elements in matrix with random integers

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I have an `4x4` array with some values like this:

```
A =

     4     0     0     0
     0     2     0     0
     0     0     3     0
     1     0     0     0
```

How can I populate the zeros with random integers from 1 to 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B=A+~A.*randi(4,size(A))
```

Generates a random matrix of size A,  multiplies by a logical matrix(~A) which has a zero where A has a value, then adds to A.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `randi` to generate random integers, and a mask for the location of the zeros

```
A = [ 4     0     0     0
      0     2     0     0
      0     0     3     0
      1     0     0     0];
m = A == 0;
A(m) = randi ([1 4], nnz (m), 1);
```

The advantage of this over, a more typical `B = A + ~A .* randi (4, size (A))`, is to save in some computation time. It generates the exact number of required random numbers and assigns them to specific locations. It does not make an addition and multiplication for all the elements.